# Ajax autocomplete input field unfounded data aren't sending

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem. I used Ajax autocomplete for input field and fetch my listed data form database. Its worked nicely but **I want when not found data then input field not send any data to sql.**

```
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Country Name" />  
                <div id="countryList"></div>
```

**Ajax**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#country').keyup(function(){  
           var query = $(this).val();  
           if(query != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"search.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{query:query},  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          $('#countryList').fadeIn();  
                          $('#countryList').html(data);  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
           $('#country').val($(this).text());  
           $('#countryList').fadeOut();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', 'body', function(){  
           $('#countryList').fadeOut();  
      });
 });
```

Comment: what are you trying to ask, elaborate more.. ?

Comment: is this is the thing you are asking     if( query.length>0)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `required` parameter in HTML to make a field required. This way, you can't submit the form before you haven't filled in something in this field.

```
<input required
    type="text" name="country"
    id="country" class="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter Country Name">
```